# Exception casting valid JSON with Java

Tags: java, json, exception

I have a **JSON string**:

```
{
    "_id": -1,
    "create_date": 0,
    "update_date": 0,
    "description": "test",
    "active": true
}
```

In Java, I try to parse it using **org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser** :

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
org.json.simple.JSONObject jsonObject = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(phoneJSON);
```

I try to retrieve the `_id` field value:

```
String s_id = ((String) jsonObject.get("_id"));
```

but encounter the following exception:

```
java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

Furthermore, if I display the field value in the console:

```
System.out.println("print value -  _id: "+jsonObject.get("_id"));
```

I get:

```
print value -  _id: -1
```

output in the console.

I have seen this post:

[java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704211/java-lang-long-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-string)

But is does not help me.

What am I not understanding?

Comment: aren't you looking for String.valueOf(long) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `.toString()` method to convert Long to String.

```
String strLong = Long.toString(jsonObject.get("_id")));
```

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html):

> Returns a String object representing this Long's value.

Also, the reason `println` outputs the value in the console is because `PrintStream.println` has an overload that [takes](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/PrintStream.java#PrintStream.println%28java.lang.Object%29) an `Object`, and then calls its `toString` method.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the parsing process. But in the casting process of the following line:

```
String s_id = ((String) jsonObject.get("_id"));
```

`jsonObject.get("_id")` returns - as specified by the error - a `java.lang.Long`, and you later cast it to `String`.

You can solve this, for instance with:

```
String s_id = jsonObject.get("_id").toString();
```

In Java the `(String)` is **not a conversion**, but a downcast. Since a `String` is not a subclass of `Long`, it will error. You can however call `.toString()` that will transform the `Long` in a textual representation.

---

The reason:

```
System.out.println("print value -  _id: "+jsonObject.get("_id"));
```

works is because if you "add" an object to a string, the `toString` method is called automatically. Implicitly you have written:

```
System.out.println("print value -  _id: "+Objects.toString(jsonObject.get("_id")));
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of _id is correctly identified as Long (-1 in the example) when you use `jsonObject.get("_id")`.

If you want a String use `jsonObject.getString("_id").`

Comment: A string should be able to hold ANY long or Int.  Why the exception?

Comment: In Java not really, they have different classes. You can convert between them, for e.g. Integer.valueOf(<string>) or Integer.toString(<int>).

Comment: @AndroidAddict: because java doesn't support overloaded cast operators. In C# you can. But a `(String)` conversion in Java only means downcasting (not converting) and since you cannot downcast a `Long` to a `String`, it will error.

Comment: I want to represent the long value in a string.  I do it all the time, why can't I do it here?  I am really confused on this!

Comment: You can represent an integer in a string, try jsonObject.getString("_id")

Answer (score 1):

Why do you except the "_id" field to be a string?

Its value is -1 (opposed to "-1") so it is actually a Long instead of String.

However, if you need string, you can cast it via

```
String s_id = String.valueOf(jsonObject.get("_id"));
```